# What's the purpose of Series instead of lists in Pandas and Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Why doesn't Pandas build DataFrames directly from lists? Why was such a thing as a series created in the first place?

Or: If the data in a DataFrame is actually stored in memory as a collection of Series, why not just use a collection of lists?

Yet another way to ask the same question: what's the purpose of Series over lists?

Comment: Are you familiar with NumPy and the advantages of `ndarrays` over lists for some tasks? In many ways, a `Series` is just a NumPy array backed up with an index and augmented with other methods useful in data analysis.

Comment: Probably worth reading about some of the cool things you can do with Series that you can't do with a simple list: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dsintro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't going to be a very complete answer, but hopefully is an intuitive "general" answer.

Pandas doesn't use a list as the "core" unit that makes up a `DataFrame` because `Series` objects make assumptions that lists do not. A list in python makes very little assumptions about what is inside, it could be pretty much anything, which makes it great as a core component of python.

However, if you want to build a more specialized package that gives you extra functionality liked `Pandas`, then you want to create your own "core" data object and start building extra functionality on top of that. Compared with lists, you can do a lot more with a custom `Series` object (as witnessed by pulling a single column from a `DataFrame` and seeing what methods are available to the output).